# RTTI for virtual inheritance (without virtual functions)

Tags: c++, gcc, rtti, abi

I've noticed that both Clang and GCC generate typeinfo for non-polymorphic types with virtual inheritance. As I understood, this is not required by standard. Why they do this, and how it is used?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

struct VirtualBase {};
struct Derived : virtual VirtualBase{};

int main()
{
    Derived md;
    uintptr_t **vptr = (uintptr_t **)&md;
    std::type_info * tinfo = (std::type_info *)(*vptr)[-1];
    std::cout << tinfo->name() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `7Derived`

After reading ABI documentation I've expected to receive a segfault instead of the answer:

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable-components

> The typeinfo pointer is a valid pointer for polymorphic classes, i.e.
>   those with virtual functions, and is zero for non-polymorphic classes.

Comment: Also see [How to set up LLVM-style RTTI for your class hierarchy](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html).

Comment: @jww this is not directly related to llvm.

Comment: gcc, icc and Clang will use virtual tables to provide the RTTI necessary for dynamic_cast to work in the presence of virtual bases. C++ vtables are also needed  for other non-polymorphic concepts.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174373/c-is-a-class-with-virtual-base-but-without-virtual-functions-polymorphic-and

Comment: @user1512 No, dynamic cast is not allowed for non-polymorphic classes. I got compile error if I try to do this for classes with virutal inheritance (but w/o virtual functions).